# Controlling the number of requests in Taurus

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I am just wondering how I can control the number of requests in Taurus / Jmeter?

Let's say I have to use an external file where there are prepared data for the test. I have to know how many data I should make for data (i.e. how many requests will be fired by Taurus / JMeter).

I found this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/controlling-number-hits-second-performance-tests-using-taurus) which says that the `throughput` setting can be used for that. However I got the following exception when I added this single setting (`throughput: 2`) to my yaml file:

```
2018-05-31 13:08:11,743 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/vikhor/projects/temp/taurus/test_SOAP/2018-05-31_13-07-54.930576/modified_requests.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
...
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer
```

I haven't installed JMeter, let Taurus installed it.
Any idea how to fix this issue (found [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codename-taurus/WSN4WnkAga4) but didn't help) or how to control the number of the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have JPGC@ Throughput Shaping Timer plugin installed with the jmeter.

Please check the below image:-

[image]

If you didnt find it then it may be the cause. Then, you can install it by any of the two methods:-

1- Use Jmeter [plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. Direct download the [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Prefer plugin manager as it will be helpful in future to install other plugins.
Hope it helps.